# Android - Toolbar - Change button sequence

Tags: android

I am trying to create a toolbar with a back arrow and title left justified, and two buttons right justified.  The two buttons are not displaying in the sequence that I want.

Here is the layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_child_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="#aa492f"
            android:onClick="onClickExit"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_24dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="#aa492f"
            android:onClick="onClickCashIn"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_payment_white_24dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="#aa492f"
            android:onClick="onClickPay"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send_white_24dp"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <GridLayout .../>

</LinearLayout>
```

I would like for button ic_payment_white_24dp to appear on the left, and for button ic_send_white_24dp to appear on the right.  But they appear in the reverse sequence:

[image: screenshot]

What am I doing wrong?  I tried experimenting with many different properties, e.g. android:layout_toRightOf, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: one of your imageButtons doesn't have an id. add it to be able to place it correctly in the layout in relation to your other views

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this `xml` for `toolbar` design.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
  android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:weightSum="1.45">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_toolBar"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.15"
                android:gravity="center">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/back_arrow" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolBarText"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.99"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/notification_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center|right"
                android:layout_weight="0.30">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/notifcation_imageView"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:src="@drawable/payment"
                    android:tint="@android:color/white" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/logout_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:tint="@android:color/white" 
                    android:src="@drawable/send"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have to use

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

to inflate menu for toolbar and Xml should be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/place_picker"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_map"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:title="Search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/random_place"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_shuffle"
    android:title="Pick a Random place"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

and to rearrange items you have to adjust `android:orderInCategory="2"` for proper arrangement

Comment: my guess is that this is the more correct solution, to define these items as a menu.  but for now i needed a quick fix, to change the sequence of the items on the toolbar.  many thanks for getting back to me.